# Theme option : having the ability to select among several predefined headers

Tags: theme-options, headers, theme-customizer

I'm in the process of creating my first theme, and I'm using Quark as a starter theme.

I would like the theme to have various options, one being header selection. (let's say 5 different headers - when selected, the header will show site wide.)

I also would like to implement various headers whose code are available on codepen, but what I'm struggling with is giving users the ability to select their header of choice.

Let' say I want to implement this menu first : http://codepen.io/WhiteWolfWizard/pen/CJLeu.

I've read the Codex for get header function, and I also saw this :

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

It's not suitable to what I'm trying to do, since it shows a header on a per-page basis.

So I was wondering : where the code for the different headers should be, and how can I give the users the ability to select the headers ? (either with option tree, Customizer API, or a better solution if you have any)

Thanks

PS : I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: Add customizer settings for headers, and then with `get_theme_mod()` you can see what option is selected from customizer. based on that you can add your custom headers (create separate `.php` files for each header).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hope it's not too much to ask, but where and how should I use `get_theme_mod` ?

Comment: look at my answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you need customizer options. You can put this in `customizer.php` and include that file in your `functions.php` or you can just put it in `functions.php` directly.

```
add_action('customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register');

function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    /**
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    SECTION: Header
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    **/
    $wp_customize->add_section('section_header', array(
        'title'          => esc_html__('Header', 'mytheme'),
        'description'    => esc_attr__( 'Choose one of three different Header Styles', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority'       => 1,
    ));

        /**
        Header Styles
        **/
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_styles', array(
            'default'    => '',
        ));
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'header_styles', array(
            'label'      => esc_html__( 'Header Styles', 'mytheme' ),
            'section'    => 'section_header',
            'type'       => 'select',
            'choices'    => array(
                'style_1'    => esc_html__('Header 1', 'mytheme'),
                'style_2'    => esc_html__('Header 2', 'mytheme'),
                'style_3'    => esc_html__('Header 3', 'mytheme'),
            ),
        ));

}
```

This will give you a dropdown settings in your customizer.

[image]

With that you can, wherever your header element tag `<header>` is located, add any styling or even include separate file if you want.

Say that your header is in a file called `header_style_1.php` located in a `partials` folder, and it's included in the `header.php` file as

```
get_template_part('partials/header_style_1);
```

You can add files `header_style_2.php` and `header_style_3.php` and in your `header.php` just add:

```
$header_style = get_theme_mod('header_styles', 'style_1');

get_template_part('partials/header_'.$header_layout);
```

This will fetch any of that templates you created for your header.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi man, thanks a whole lot, I got the first part working. I haven't done the second part yet (`header_style_X.php`) as I got to do some urgent "real life" stuff. As I get back tomorrow, I'll do the rest, and mark your answer as the right one for my need. But huge thanks again.

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks again for your help. I guess I can use the same code to have a bunch of 404 page templates now. :)

Comment: Sure, you can use it for anything you like (customizer). For color change, radio buttons etc. I've made a list of custom controls that you can check out [here](https://github.com/dingo-d/wordpress-theme-customizer-extra-custom-controls). Feel free to +1 and accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: well I did, but didn't pick up for some reasons ?

Comment: thank you very much!!!! I've done this almost perfectly... but I like to insert in ***style_1*** a variable to get the correct heading: style1, style2, style3.... Is it possible?? $header_style = get_theme_mod('header_styles', 'style_1'); get_template_part('partials/header_'.$header_style); Thank a lot!!

Comment: @SergioLopez do not derail other peoples questions by posting questions as the solution to their answer. If you have a new question you should create a brand new question. This isn't a discussion forum/thread, it's a Q&A site, and posting comments as answers to get around  the low reputation restrictions will get your account auto-banned by t he antispam system

Answer (score 0):

With Option Tree, you can use it like this way:

Lets say you will provide 5 different header designs. Create 5 header files:

1. header.php
2. header-two.php
3. header-three.php
4. header-four.php
5. header-five.php

Now you can check it like:

```
if (ot_get_option('your_header_selection_key') == 'one'){
    get_header();
} elseif (ot_get_option('your_header_selection_key') == 'two'){
    get_header('two');
} elseif (ot_get_option('your_header_selection_key') == 'three'){
    get_header('three');
} elseif (ot_get_option('your_header_selection_key') == 'four'){
    get_header('four');
} elseif (ot_get_option('your_header_selection_key') == 'five'){
    get_header('five');
}
```

You can wrap these code in a function inside `functions.php` and call from page templates, instead writing them on every template file.

This is just an idea. You can use [Customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/) with this same idea, if you do not use Option Tree.

Comment: not that using option tree is a smart thing, but at least you could have linked to it ;)

Comment: @THE Sufi : Thanks for your help. If I understand correctly, the given code goes in `functions.php`, but how do I make the header setting in option tree panel. ( I got it installed in theme mode). @Mark Kaplun : Thanks for your answer as well, but why exactly is Option Tree a bad idea ?

Comment: @TrynaCode, most frameworks of this kind do not really add much value to things that you can write in 10 lines of code, and they become a limitation and liability as time passes by as you need to not only understand your code but also to understand the internal of the framework. If you just looking to do something quick then maybe it is ok to use such a thing, but if you want to create a theme that you will maintain a long time, I think it is better to understand the relevant WP APIs sooner then later.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, Fair enough. I'm more than keen on going the full WP route. Would you have some clues on how to achieve this with the said route ?

Comment: @TrynaCode, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod is key to storing theme settings in the DB and the customizer is the main way to introduce GUI for the settings

Comment: @MarkKaplun I was actually giving him an idea about how to meet his goal.

Comment: @TrynaCode If you are using Option Tree, then you can check their documentation. You can use any of the: radio, radio image or select and provide your header name as options to select.